# How to insert a json object into a mysql field and read it back?

Tags: mysql, json

I have an array which i must convert to a json variable and store it in a mysql table field and I do this by the following code:

```
$arr = array(
        'title_it' => $category->title->attributes()->it,
        'desc_it' => $category->desc->attributes()->it,
        'tags_it' => $category->tags->attributes()->it,

        'title_es' => $category->title->attributes()->es,
        'desc_es' => $category->desc->attributes()->es,
        'tags_es' => $category->tags->attributes()->es,

        'title_fr' => $category->title->attributes()->fr,
        'desc_fr' => $category->desc->attributes()->fr,
        'tags_fr' => $category->tags->attributes()->fr,

        'title_en' => $category->title->attributes()->en,
        'desc_en' => $category->desc->attributes()->en,
        'tags_en' => $category->tags->attributes()->en,

        'title_de' => $category->title->attributes()->de,
        'desc_de' => $category->desc->attributes()->de,
        'tags_de' => $category->tags->attributes()->de
        );
    $params = mysql_real_escape_string(json_encode($arr));

    $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO category_tags (id, params) VALUES ($id, '$params')") or die("could not connect");
```

Then I want to read this field and display only the attribute title_it  I tried something like:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM article_tags WHERE id = $id LIMIT 0,1") or die("could not connect");    
$row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
$jsoni = json_encode($row['params']); 

$decoded = json_decode($jsoni, true);
echo $decoded->title_it;
```

but no result.  Also, the json is stored in a strange format. the mysql field looks like this:

{"title_it":{"0":"titolo1"},"desc_it":{"0":"descrizione1"},"tags_it":{"0":"tags1"},"title_es":{"0":"titulo1"},"desc_es":{"0":"descripci\u00f3n1"},"tags_es":{"0":"etiquetas1"},"title_fr":{"0":"titre1"},"desc_fr":{"0":"description1"},"tags_fr":{"0":"balises1"},"title_en":{"0":"title1"},"desc_en":{"0":"description1"},"tags_en":{"0":"tags1"},"title_de":{"0":"titel1"},"desc_de":{"0":"beschreibung1"},"tags_de":{"0":"etikett1"}}

So... What is the correct way to insert this json into a mysql field and then to read only a parameter of this field?

Comment: Please, **DO NOT** use `mysql_query` in new applications. It's deprecated, dangerous if used incorrectly, and is being removed from future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) will help you avoid making mistakes like this.

Comment: You are writing to `category_tags` and reading from `article_tags`?

Comment: Why are you doing `$jsoni = json_encode($row['params']);`?  Isn't `'params'` already a json string?  I think you just need `$decoded = json_decode($row['params'], true);`  P.S. `,true` makes it into an associative array, *not* an object.  You need `echo $decoded['title_it'];`

Comment: i messed the table names while posting the question. :)

Comment: Thank You, that did the trick:
$decoded = json_decode($row['params'], true);
echo $decoded['title_it'][0];

Comment: @RrezartaMuja: I added an answer.  When creating you `$arr`, you need to cast the values as strings.  That will let you just do `echo $decoded['title_it'];` :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that SimpleXML doesn't return you strings when you get attribute values.  When you do `$category->title->attributes()->it` you are actually being returned a `SimpleXMLElement` object.  It looks like this:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#3 (1) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "Your_Value"
}
```

When serialized in JSON, this is converted to: `{0: "Your_Value"}`, that's what you're seeing when you decode.

You need to cast them as strings when you add them to your array:

```
$arr = array(
    'title_it' => (string)$category->title->attributes()->it,
    'desc_it' => (string)$category->desc->attributes()->it,
    'tags_it' => (string)$category->tags->attributes()->it,
    # etc.
);
```

---

When you get your data, you don't need to `json_encode` it again, you *only* need to `json_decode` it.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM category_tags WHERE id = $id LIMIT 0,1") or die("could not connect");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($query);

$decoded = json_decode($row['params'], true);
// The ",true" makes it into an array, not an object
echo $decoded['title_it'];
```

Answer (score -1):

well it looks like your

```
$category->title->attributes()->it,
```

type values are returning arrays instead of strings. and as we know php arrays are always associative (sigh), so you get

```
Array(0=>"titolo1")
```

which becomes the object

```
{"0":"titolo1"}
```

Comment: This is not entirely true.  PHP arrays are ***NOT*** always associative.  This is probably happening because the "array" is actually an object, or because its keys were modified (with something like `array_splice`, so they are not in order).

Comment: <categories>
  <category id="1">
   <title it="titolo1" es="titulo1" fr="titre1" en="title1" de="titel1" />
 <desc it="descrizione1" es="descripci贸n1" fr="description1" en="description1" de="beschreibung1" />
 <tags it="tags1" es="etiquetas1" fr="balises1" en="tags1" de="etikett1" />
  </category>
</categories>

Comment: this is the xml file from which i read with this code:  foreach($xml->category as $category){....}